# Rails: How to show dynamic html content in the browser without escaping it and without causing XSS attack

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, xss

I want to diplay html content in the browser without escaping it.my code is as below.

```
<% @mydata = "<p>paragraph</p><h1>Test</h1><script>alert('got your cookie')</script><h1>another test</h1>" %>

<%= sanitize @mydata  %>
```

here i can't use raw method because  `raw` method will execute malicious javascript code and hence i am using rails `sanitize` method. but the problem is that rails sanitize method deleting `<script>alert('got your cookie')</scipt>` line and not showing it in the browser.

I am getting output as below

paragraph

## Test

## another test

---

My expected output is as below

paragraph

## Test

alert('got your cookie')

## another test

is there any way to unescape html content and escape only javascript content from the user input?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

in rails you can whitelist tags:

```
<%= sanitize @comment.body, tags: %w(strong em a), attributes: %w(href) %>
```

- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

### other ways how to do it:

**option 1**

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.escapeHTML('<h1>hi</h1><script>aeuoau</script>')
# => "&lt;h1&gt;hi&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;script&gt;aeuoau&lt;/script&gt;"
```

- http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html

**option 2**

if you are building something like blog website where you would display html  code:

- http://coderay.rubychan.de/
- https://github.com/rubychan/codera

**option 3**

if you just want to remove malicious HTML and keep common text tags like `p`, `b`, `ul`, ....

```
raw(simple_format('<h1>hi</h1><script>aeuoau</script>'))
# => "<p><h1>hi</h1>aeuoau</p>"
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format

note: simple_format will "format" your code => would wrap `\n` in `<p></p>`, etc.

**other gems**

- https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize
- https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah

Comment: in option 3 i am getting output as "<p></p><h1>hi</h1><p></p>" and not the one that you have mentioned.

Comment: i want to print the content of the script tag but don't want browser to execute the script tag code.

Comment: I was runing it from `rails console` like this `helper.raw(helper.simple_format('<h1>hi</h1><script>aeuoau</script>'))
`  it may be that it's using different default config when displayed in Rails controller/view

Comment: i tried in console and still showing me output as "<p><h1>hi</h1></p>" . it is not showing content of script tag.

Comment: ...then I'm recommending that `CGI` approach `<code><pre><%= CGI.escapeHTML('<h1>hi</h1><script>aeuoau</script>') %></pre></code>`

Comment: I'm running `Rails 4.2.5.1` on ruby `2.2.4` with but-load of  configuration  and gems around the app that I'm not fully aware of , it may just be that you with fresh Rails project you have different (better fresh) configuration, or we just have different versions of `ActiveSupport`

Comment: my question is not to escape html content. i have to escape only javascript content because it can cause xss security issue.